# Post on Facebook page wall or timeline

Tags: facebook

As FaceBook launched a new concept of pages, I created a page, but I am not able to find any C# SDK for posting on that page's timeline from code.

Answer (score 0):

First you need C# SDK 
you can download from here 
http://csharpsdk.org/

may be you need manage_page permission to get a page access token

you can get a page access token using this Graph Request http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts

after getting page access token you can post a on page wall using this code

```
        var fb = new Facebook.FacebookClient(PageAccessToken);
        var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postArgs["link"] = "http://www.foo.com";
        postArgs["name"] = "Click Here To View";
        postArgs["message"] = Message;
        fb.Post("[pageid]/feed/", postArgs);
```